# How do I pass my username and password into a perl script from an ansible role?

Tags: perl, ansible, mq

I have a perl script for creating ssl certificates on a IBM MQ qmgr. The script needs a username and password for it to work.

I have an ansible role that calls a ready made perl script to create a MQ qmgr and another to create a ssl kdb. Like this:

```
- name: Create MQ Queue Manager
  shell: "./CreateQmgr.sh -m {{MQ_QMGR1}}"
  args:
    chdir: /opt/wmqinf/utilities

- name: SSL the new Qmgr
  shell: "./renewSSL.pl -S {{SSL_PEER1}} -U -m {{MQ_QMGR1}} -G {{GBGF}}"
  args:
    chdir: /opt/wmqinf/utilities
```

The playbook / role fails when it can't create the ssl kdb as no username is entered.

Is there a way I can pass the .pl script my username and password for it to work?

Comment: Should not SSL rely on public keys or some such? Adding your password in plain text sounds like a huge security issue.

Comment: I don't really get the point from your question: is your script waiting for those information interactively ? In such a case please see the `expect` module. Moreover, taking @TLP comment into account, you should seriously consider using ansible-vault to store your password (and eventually username).

Comment: Apologies, the script starts/invoked from my username and password. It doesn't use these as part of the cert.

Comment: @Zeitounator yes, it waits for my username and password as a prompt.

Comment: What is prompting for the password?   The `renewSSL.pl` must call something else like `runmqakm`, is this what is prompting?

Comment: Did you have a look at the expect module?

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. such as modify your perl script to accept extra command line arguments. however, this should/might work

```
shell: "./renewSSL.pl -S {{SSL_PEER1}} -U -m {{MQ_QMGR1}} -G {{GBGF}}" <(echo -n "str2") <(echo -n "str3")
```